# Webform confirmation message alternate source

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

How can I override the default webform source for the form submission confirmation message and fetch it from a 'CCK' (I still can't remember what they are now called in D7) element instead?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an approach similar to that outlined here: http://drupal.org/node/1245298

Steps:

1. Use hook_menu to create your confirmation page path
2. Set confirmation page in webform ( e.g path is confirmation/%nid/%sid to pass parameters )
3. Load relevant webform and/or submission in menu callback
4. Display confirmation message as required.

Comment: +1 Good answer @David Thomas very clearly lays out what to do. This suits my situation very well.